# Android kill app upon timeout as background app

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I have a question that I need help on.

I am trying to have my app killed when it goes to the background and some time has passed.

For instance, I start my application. Then, I get some message from my friend via messaging app such as WhatsApp. It's winter and I'm outside and it's cold and my hands are freezing, I decide to put my phone away. After 20 minutes, I take my phone out and when I bring my app to the foreground, I would like to see the app start again.

Right now, the app is not dying on its own as time passes and as far as I understand, the Android system does not kill apps in the background unless the extra memory is required.

How could I have my app closed in whichever activity I am in as the app goes to the background? Thanks in advance for help :D

**EDIT**

Perhaps I have not been so clear with my question.

I want to have my app close on its own after it spends certain time duration after it has been "sent back".

I was afraid to do fiddle with `onPause` and `onStop` methods because from what I understand from the activity lifecycle diagram below, `onPause` method **will always be** called and `onStop` will be called whenever an activity change happens with the new activity totally covering the previous activity. Thus, putting the timeout to kill the process in these method just seemed very risky for me.

Would there be an ensured way of killing my app process as it is sent to the background? Thanks.

[image: android activity lifecycle diagram]

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of developer options for that.

First, go to Settings>About Phone
Then repeatedly click the Build Number until you see the message that 'You are now a developer'

Then, you will see an additional option in your settings for Developer Options. Switch on the developer options, then scroll down and you will see an option 'Background process limit' set that to no process and you will achieve what you want.

**Note**: That might result in some apps not functioning properly and so it is advisable you don't do so.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I was not clear enough with my question. I wanted my app to kill its process on certain timeout duration after being sent to the background, not having the user to fiddle with their phone's settings